# Linearity of operator

Tags: functional-analysis

In the circled part of the picture, why isn't that a minus sign in place of the plus sign?
[image]

Comment: Apparently, because $T=\lim_{n\to\infty} -T_n$ (in whatever way they mean it, which seems to be "at least pointwise").

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought I was missing something about the property of operators.

Comment: Well, what your question is missing is the definition.

Comment: Here is where I saw this... http://dgriffinresources.net/m241/Week8HW2_10.pdf

Comment: Wouldn't just computing (Tn-T)ax be sufficient?

Comment: The change of minus and plus sign seems to be a typo which the author repeats as many times as he needs to end up with the desired result.

Comment: ah you are right. Thank you.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli If you want to make a quick answer I will accept it.